# Tracking changes in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

The component code has several parameters, each of which has an initial value received from the server. How can I track that one of them (or several at once) has changed its state from the original one in order to suggest that the user save the changes or reset them?

Something similar can be seen in Discord when changing the profile / server.

The solution I found using useEffect () looks redundant, because there may be many times more options.

```
const [hiddenData, setHiddenData] = useState(server.hidden_data);
const [hiddenProfile, setHiddenProfile] = useState(server.hidden_profile);
const [isChanged, setIsChanged] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (hiddenData !== server.hidden_data
  || hiddenProfile !== server.hidden_profile) {
    setIsChanged(true);
  } else {
    setIsChanged(false);
  }
}, [hiddenData, server.hidden_data, hiddenProfile, server.hidden_profile]);

return (
  <>
    {isChanged && <div>You have unsaved changes!</div>}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that?

```js
const [draftState, setDraftState] = useState(server)
const [state, setState] = useState(server)

// a more complex object with the list of changed props is fine too
const isChanged = lodash.isEqual(state, draftState)

function changeProp (prop, value) {
  setState({
    ...draftState,
    [prop]: value
  })
}

function saveState () {
  setState(draftState)
  // Persist state if needed
}
```